# How to make dependent microservice calls async?

Tags: microservices

How to make microservices call async when microservice B depends on the response of A and microservice C depend on response B?

Comment: can you explain a little more what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid chaining calls from one microservice to another in order to fulfill a client's request. It doesn't matter if the calls are synchronous or asynchronous.  This can lead to cascade failures so the availability of the system is affected.

Instead, you should gather all the needed data in background (i.e. using `cron` or events) *before* the clients' requests. In this way, if service A is down, service B continues to work.